# How to wait for node exec response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, child-process

how can I use a callback tor a promise correctly to get the result from a **node exec** in the `condole.log()` function?

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
const check = () => {
    exec(`...`, (err, stdout) => {
        if (err) {
         return false         
        }
        else {
         return true
        }
    })
}
console.log(check()) // getting undefined
```

I've tried using `.on('exit')` but none worked... would love to get some help here. THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the Promise constructor to do it yourself or you can use the **util** module to convert a callback invoking function into one that returns a promise

**Using the util module**

```
const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

const check = async () => {
  const output = await exec(`echo hi`);

  console.log(output);
};

check();
```

**Wrapping with the Promise constructor**

```
import { exec } from "child_process";
const check = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`echo hi`, (err, stdout) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(stdout);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: on both of these examples the program would throw an unhandled promise error if the call to exec returns an error. To my knowledge, OP simply wants to handle the error by returning false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the call in a promise to get the return of the callback:

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process'

const check = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    exec(`...`, (err, stdout) => {
        if (err) {
         resolve(false)       
        }
        else {
         resolve(true)
        }
    })
  })
}
```

By not rejecting on an error in the callback you can instead resolve the promise and return false instead. If you used the `reject` parameter on the promise call you would need to handle that error by chaining a `.catch()` call. To keep the implementation similar to what you already have I have omitted it and instead resolved the promise with `false`.

Then you can use `.then()` on the call to `check` and get the desired results:

```js
check().then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```